# How to handle the Variable 'max_allowed_packet' limitation in MYSQL?

Tags: java, mysql

I am sending requests to the `GOOGLE MY BUSINESS API` (com.google.api.services.mybusiness.v4) and as a response I receive the `Reviews` for our client. I collect all the reviews in a List (in java) and finally at the end, I insert them in a`MY-SQL` table. We have different clients which may have various numbers of reviews everyday, and the problem is that sometimes the process fails because this so-called **`max-allowed-packet`** limit has been exceeded.

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';
+--------------------+----------+
| Variable_name      | Value    |
+--------------------+----------+
| max_allowed_packet | 33554432 |
+--------------------+----------+
1 row in set (0.03 sec)
```

Since this value is in bytes, how can I handle this problem? I mean I have a List of info to insert so I have the **number** of records and not their volume. For the moment I am shrinking my list into sub-lists if they are more than 10000 records but there is no guarantee that less than 10K records would satisfy the `max_allowed_packet` limitation.
Plus, I cannot increase this variable according to the `DBA` policies.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Session `max_allowed_packet` option variable is read-only, i.e. you cannot alter it. If current value is too low then you must either reconfigure and restart your server (remember, this will alter memory consumption accordingly, so the server must be re-tuned), or you may simply divide your data packed to chunks (save your data using a pack of separate queries). The last option seems to be more safe.

Comment: Thank you @Akina, how would you suggest to divide, I mean I have the number of records, how can I check the volume of them? one client might have 30k records and the other 100k. it is not even guaranteed to meet the limitation by divide based on the numbers

Comment: Imagine that you have a row to be inserted. You know the columns datatypes, for string type you know the lengths, and you know the datatypes overheads. Hence you can easily calculate the size of the row. Do this for each row to be inserted. I recommend you to use chunks which are ~25-30% in size of `max_allowed_packet` value, this guarantees that you won't exceed the limitation.